# Why is my input statement not transferring float into the list?

Tags: python, list

[Pycharm Screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhb7z.png)

```
#Accept a list of 5 float numbers as an input from the user numlist=[]
```

for i in range(0,5):
numlist[i]=numlist.append(float(input("Input a number:")))

print(numlist)

#Output: [None, None, None, None, None]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `numlist[i]=`. The `append` method returns `None` hence the elements in the list are being replaced with `None`.